# Ad Group October 2nd 2013 changes: bid_info is returning still numeric indexes instead of strings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, adgroup

we have enabled the October 2nd 2013 breaking changes for our application yesterday, the change to the application settings is already confirmed. If I submit `bid_info` in the new format (with strings instead of numeric indexes) it works:

```
"bid_info": {
  "CLICKS": 75
}
```

When I try to read the ad group with a request to its url later, I get a `bid_info` and a `max_bid` setting in parallel (I expected that `max_bid` will be removed in October 2nd-mode), but the `bid_info` contains the numeric index and not the expected CLICKS-string:

```
(...)
"adgroup_status": 3,
"bid_type": 1,
"max_bid": 75,
"bid_info": {
   "1": 75
},
"ad_status": 3,
"locations": [
  3
],
(...)
```

Any suggestions for that? Is this bug or by design? Or did something went wrong with the activation of the October 2nd changes for our application?

Bye

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Same for me but without activating october 2nd breaking changes...
It's quite strange to have number as name field and it is not allowed in languages like in c#.

It should be this kind of info:
A dictionary of values that you place on your bid

```
CPM={'REACH':cent_value}
CPC={'CLICKS':cent_value}
oCPM or CPA={'ACTIONS':cent_value}
```

I've 1, 38, 44, 55 in place of this.

Update, it's actually this: 
Actions: 55
Reach: 44
Clicks: 1
Social Impressions: 38

More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/optimizedcpm/

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/539767489417940?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5203fffd63da04c48847913

I actually filed a ticket against this. The Facebook bug response said it would be fixed on July 17th, however a contact at Facebook elevated this ticket after it was not fixed on July 17th, and it is now being currently worked on.

We were told it should be functional by the end of August.